# Iframe w/ Content Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

This is my first question on StackOverflow, so big thanks to all the community.
I'm currently trying to work out a problem and can't find any solutions:

I want to display content into the Iframe, which has to be automatically sized (the height)

Currently, everthings goes according to plan, except one thins: 
When I go on the page, the iframe content is correctly loaded, but the Iframe isn't the right size. I have to refresh one time, then it will be the correct size. here's my code:

```
<script>
  function resizeIframe(obj) {
        obj.style.width = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollWidth + 'px';
        obj.style.height = 0;
        obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
  }
</script>

<iframe  frameborder="0" width="1000" scrolling="no" onload="resizeIframe(this)" src="/myurl.url"></iframe>
```

Any help would be very much appreciated !

Thank you

Comment: Make a fiddle or something for reproduce error.

Comment: Try placing your script after the iframe creation. i.e.
    `<iframe>....</iframe>

    <script>....

    </script>`

I could be wrong but worth a shot

Comment: Yes I also tried ! But it also failed, I'm pretty sure there must be some sort of loading priorities on the main html page but can't figure how it can be changed (first loading the iframe, then it's content)

Answer (score 0):

You could tell it to refresh the page once loaded or give your function a timeout setting to wait before it runs.

Have you tried adding the function in a    document.ready(function() {});

Comment: I tried to apply a one-time reload process but I have the pop-up window "do you want to reload" which isn't that great. I'll try out the document.ready, and i'll come back with news (and good results i hope !)

Answer (score 0):

can you try this?

```
document.getElementById('<iframe id>').onload = function (event) {
    var IframWin = event.target.contentWindow;
    $(IframWin.document).ready(function(){
          //your resize code
    });

    //I think this gonna work
    IframWin.$(document).ready(function(){
          //your resize code
    });
};
```

Edit->
if that iframe is yours, you can create document ready function. And you can call parent function from iframe.

in iframe->

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    parent.resizeFunction();
});
```